# How to have a vec of Boxes which implement 2 traits?

Tags: rust, vector, traits

In rust I would like to have a vec containing items which implement 2 traits. However when I try to implement it like so, I get the error `only auto traits can be used as additional traits in a trait object`:

```rust
let mut v : Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait + std::fmt::Display>> = Vec::new();
```

FairPlay, I read the error message in full and defined a Trait which combines the two:

```rust
pub trait FormattableDoer: std::fmt::Display + MyTrait{}
```

The have a Vec of Boxes to that:

```rust
let mut v: Vec<Box<dyn FormattableDoer>> = Vec::new();
```

However the compiler can't seem to detect that my struct has implemented those things separately and I get the error `the trait bound MyStruct: FormattableDoer is not satisfied`.

I read about using a trait alias, but that's not in stable so I'd rather not use it.

Is this possible in rust? It seems like a common thing to want to do and I'm surprised that the answer isn't simple (or maybe it is and I have missed it!). I'm also thinking that maybe I have approached the problem all wrong and I'm attempting to do something in an 'non rusty' way. If that's the case, what is the preferred way of having a vector of things which are displayable and have some other trait?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=pub%20trait%20MyTrait%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20dewit(%26self)-%3Ei32%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Apub%20struct%20MyStruct%7B%0A%20%20%20%20i%3A%20i32%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20MyTrait%20for%20MyStruct%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20dewit(%26self)-%3Ei32%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.i%20%2B%205%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20std%3A%3Afmt%3A%3ADisplay%20for%20MyStruct%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20fmt(%26self%2C%20f%3A%20%26mut%20std%3A%3Afmt%3A%3AFormatter%3C%27_%3E)%20-%3E%20std%3A%3Afmt%3A%3AResult%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20write!(f%2C%20%22i%20%3D%20%7B%7D%22%2C%20self.i)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Apub%20trait%20FormattableDoer%3A%20std%3A%3Afmt%3A%3ADisplay%20%2B%20MyTrait%7B%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20test%20%3D%20MyStruct%7Bi%3A5%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22test%3D%20%7B%7D%22%2C%20test)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Flet%20mut%20v%20%3A%20Vec%3CBox%3Cdyn%20MyTrait%20%2B%20std%3A%3Afmt%3A%3ADisplay%3E%3E%20%3D%20Vec%3A%3Anew()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20v%3A%20Vec%3CBox%3Cdyn%20FormattableDoer%3E%3E%20%3D%20Vec%3A%3Anew()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20v.push(Box%3A%3Anew(MyStruct%7Bi%3A1%7D))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20for%20item%20in%20v%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20result%20%3D%20item.dewit()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22item%20%3D%20%7B%7D%2C%20result%20%3D%20%7B%7D%22%2C%20item%2C%20result)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D) with a MWE and a use case.

Answer (score 9):

You're almost there. You need a marker trait that implements both parents, as you've already done

```
pub trait FormattableDoer: std::fmt::Display + MyTrait {}
```

Then you need a [blanket implementation](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/what-are-blanket-implementations/49904) which takes those two traits to your new trait.

```
impl<T: std::fmt::Display + MyTrait> FormattableDoer for T {}
```

Now everything that implements `std::fmt::Display` *and* `MyTrait` will implement `FormattableDoer` automatically, and since `FormattableDoer` is a single trait, it can be used as a trait object.

Then just use `Box<dyn FormattableDoer>` like you've already tried.

Answer (score 3):

You still need to implement `FormattableDoer` for your struct. In the playground you posted, you're not doing that. Simply add

```rust
impl FormattableDoer for MyStruct {}
```

and you should be all done.

No user-defined traits are auto-implemented, even if they contain no methods or associated types.