# How can I assign a value to a variable where the type of a generic trait is not known until runtime?

Tags: rust, traits

Apologies in advance, this is probably a trivial question, but I don't even know what to search for an answer. I want to read files that might or might not be zip compressed. Depending on the file extension, I need to either create a `Reader` from a simple `io::File` or from a `BGZFReader<File>`. `Reader` will be happy with anything that implements `Read+Seek`. The - non-working - code should look something like this:

```rust
let file_reader = if filename.as_ref().extension().unwrap_or_default() == "gz"
    {   
        let in_file = BGZFReader::new(File::open(filename)?)?;
        Reader::new(in_file)
    }
    else
    {
        let in_file = File::open(filename)?;
        Reader::new(in_file)
    };
```

But of course this doesn't work, because `Reader<File>` is not the same as `Reader<BGZFReader<File>>`. Is there a way to say that my variable `file_reader` can be any instance of `Reader`, irrespective of what exact implementation of `Read+Seek` I'm using?

The reason I want to define `file_reader` generically is because there are multiple files I need to open and then pass to the downstream code. Each could be compressed or not, so writing `if/else` statements for all possible combinations would become unmanageable very quickly.

Comment: You could define an `enum` with both variants, or return e.g. `Box<dyn Read>`

Comment: You could also define a function with signature `fn(file_reader: impl Read)` for what happens next in the function, and then call it in each branch (and then no need to assign to `file_reader` at all).

Comment: @vallentin sorry, I don't see how an `enum` would solve the issue here, wouldn't that be the same as `if file.extension()=="gz" {...} else {...}`? 

I _do_ think I need to somhow `Box` `in_file`, but I'm not very confident with `Box` yet - I'd be grateful for a code example!

Comment: @BallpointBen ah, but I don't think that solves my problem. I need to 1. create a `Reader` for file1 (which can be zip or not), 2. create a `Reader` for file 2 (which can be zip or not), 3. create a `Processor` that takes `reader1` and `reader2` as input. How would I achieve this (without combinatorial explosion of if/else blocks) with your suggestion?

Comment: @DaGaMs Depending on what `Processor` accepts, then you could have a `trait GenericReader` which does not have any generic parameters nor associated items. Then you could do `impl<T> GenericReader for Reader<T>`. Then you'll be able to `Box<dyn GenericReader>`. Thus being able to have multiple in a `Vec<Box<dyn GenericReader>>`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to hints in the comments, I came up with this solution:

```rust
trait ReadAndSeek: Read+Seek {}
impl <R: Read+Seek> ReadAndSeek for R {}

fn open_file<P: AsRef<Path> + Debug>(path: P) -> Result<Reader<Box<dyn ReadAndSeek>>>
{
    if path.as_ref().extension().unwrap_or_default() == "gz"
    {
        let in_file = BGZFReader::new(File::open(path)?)?;
        Ok(Reader::new(Box::new(in_file)))
    }
    else
    {
        let in_file = File::open(path)?;
        Ok(Reader::new(Box::new(in_file)))
    }
}
```

and downstream:

```rust
let read_file = open_file(read_bed)?;
let coord_file = open_file(coord_bed)?;

let processor = Processor::new(read_file, coord_file)?;
```

The two things I didn't understand initially were:

1. Creating a compound trait as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71905183/how-to-have-a-vec-of-boxes-which-implement-2-traits)
2. `Box`ing the inner file reader with a `dyn` trait